# Need excel coding to pushing the incoming flow jobs

Tags: excel

I have a query , I would like to create a excel template which should update me the time required for required for the jobs comes in
For instance 
I have 30 employee who can work works on 20 request from 1 AM -2 AM with effort involved will be 3 hours i.e 180 minutes

If we have about 20 request incoming how can we automatically excel whould update the time required

May be 210 Minutes or 240 Minutes somehting like that

can u guide me

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you provide examples of what you are expecting to see.

Comment: Need to find time management need for the inflow of jobs I have 30 Employee who can ave complete 39 minutes of effort involved work (i.e 6.5*6=39 minutes) .. so the inflow of jobs needs to be extended ,, the excel should automatically cal the the time required for the inflow of request

Comment: Eg .. 30 Emplyee Cell A 
      6.5 per hour cell B
No of jobs in queue 200*6= 1200 minutes of work involved 
Time required for the coming request --  This should be automactially updated if the first 3 cell Value is updated

Comment: This superficially sounds like auto-calculate is turned off.   Normally if you change the any cell, whether a value or a formula, excel will recalculate the whole workbook.  However it can spontaneously switch to manual mode.   Go to "File"  ->  "Options" then select  "Formulas" on the LHS and check which is selected under 'Calculation Options'